# Angularjs migration from 1.2.1 to 1.3.9 causes issue with html5mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When i was working with 1.2.1 version i used following code for html5mode

Markup

```
<base href="/">
```

Javascript

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
             enabled: true,
             requireBase: false
      });
```

And everthing was working fine i used to get URL like http://domain/user/login without any /#/

But when i migrated from 1.2.1 to 1.3.9 i am getting URL like http://domain/user/#%2login and my routing has been stopped.
I had replaced both angular.min.js and angular.route.min.js to 1.3.9
Have i done it the right way or there is something else to be done ?

Comment: Why do you set the base but then set requireBase to false? What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I am testing in firefox/chrome and even if i omit requireBase.Still problem persist also my app is actually hosted in a particular folder eg: /angular/employeeapps/ so i had to set markup using base href.i had used both option of setting requireBase to true/false even omitted the option.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the base url to /employeeapps/ then?

Comment: I had already set base url  to "/angular/employeeapps/" just pasted the short-form of code.Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure why you were using `#` before in your link. Defeats the purpose of using html5.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue by changing

```
 <a href="#/login">Login</a> // Angular 1.2
```

To

```
 <a href="login">Login</a>   // Angular 1.3.9
```

My Config

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); // hashprefix optional
```

Base

```
<base href="/angular/employeesapp/">
```

Comment: Can you select your answer then?